# Apache Benchmark be recognized a abnormal requests by CDN

Tags: testing, stress-testing

I am using Apache Benchmark， the command is ab, I encountered a problem, some CDNs have recognized I'm using an abnormal request, but have changed the Header I request to simulate a normal request, why still recognize abnormal requests?  what is that something used to recognize

In the same environment, I am using the curl command to request is successful